# How to get multimedia component data in razor mediator?

Tags: 2013-sp1, razormediator

There is a scenario to fetch an excel file which has been inserted on a multimedia component using Tridion razor mediator.

Note: I have tried to get the excel file but I am getting the TCM Id of the component with the help of a template. But I need the excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create and use **Custom Dreamweaver Functions** from a Razor Mediator.

Refer to this below example, you can create one specific to your case.

1. Create a custom class in C# using the TOM.NET API based on **ITemplate** and **IFunctionSource**

```
[TemplateCallable]
public String PublishBinary(String compURI)
{
    Component comp = mEngine.GetObject(compURI) as Component;

    String publishPath = String.Empty;

    if (comp != null && comp.BinaryContent != null)
    {
        Binary pubBinary = mEngine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(comp);

        publishPath = pubBinary.Url;

        if (pubBinary != null)
            publishPath = pubBinary.Url;
    }

    return publishPath;
}
```

2. Create the Strong-name and add it to the **GAC** using the gacutil.exe.
3. Edit your environment **Tridion.ContentManager.config** and find the  element and inside it, the  element. Add your class dll reference.

```
    <tridion.templating>
        <functionSources>
            <functionSource type="YourCompany.Tridion.Templating.YourCustomClassExtensions" assembly="MyCustomClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc8957d6e5ee6b" />
        </functionSources>
    </tridion.templating>
```

4. Restart SDL Tridion services and COM+
5. In your TBB Razor template, you can call your template callable function as below

   ```
   @{ 
        var dw = new YourCompany.Tridion.Templating.YourCustomClassExtensions();
        dw.Initialize(TridionHelper.Engine, TridionHelper.Package);  
   }

   @dw.PublishBinary(cp.Component.Fields.Media.Id)
   ```

I hope it helps.